# Converting columns to rows Mysql Query

Tags: mysql

hi all i need some help for this:

[Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1w4H6.jpg)

help me please :S

Comment: That'd be a pivot query, and they're not supported in mysql. the workarounds get very ugly, very fast, and cannot handle arbitrary "n-wise" pivots either. do the transform in client-side code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Comment: "The transform" to which @MarcB refers could be attacked more readily if you provided the merest example of what you're trying to accomplish, since an English description is obviously evading you.